# Configuring two network cards properly so that I can access them at the same time on Linux

Tags: networking, ip, routing

I'm a bit of a beginner in Linux (I'm using CentOS 7). I have a workstation with two network cards. I configured them so that each has its own WAN. However, I can't access (using ping) them at the same time.

- 1st WAN: 172.16.0.1
- 2nd WAN: 10.101.0.10

Please have a look at the following outputs for more details:

```
[root@localhost network-scripts]# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 ens192
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG    102    0        0 ens160
10.101.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     102    0        0 ens160
172.16.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 ens192
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0


Emad Helal <emadbadr2011@gmail.com>
00:22 (5 minutes ago)
to me

ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens160: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:bf:9c:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.101.3.44/16 brd 10.101.255.255 scope global noprefixroute ens160
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::b66e:4822:ba8c:e806/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:bf:9c:af brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.0.8/24 brd 172.16.0.255 scope global noprefixroute ens192
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:febf:9caf/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:72:52:14 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:72:52:14 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
[root@localhost network-scripts]# ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (216.58.205.196) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mrs09s09-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.205.196): icmp_seq=1 ttl=115 time=38.1 ms
64 bytes from mrs09s09-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.205.196): icmp_seq=2 ttl=115 time=38.1 ms
64 bytes from mrs09s09-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.205.196): icmp_seq=3 ttl=115 time=38.1 ms
64 bytes from mrs09s09-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.205.196): icmp_seq=4 ttl=115 time=38.1 ms
64 bytes from mrs09s09-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.205.196): icmp_seq=5 ttl=115 time=38.2 ms
64 bytes from mrs09s09-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.205.196): icmp_seq=6 ttl=115 time=38.4 ms
64 bytes from mrs09s09-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.205.196): icmp_seq=7 ttl=115 time=38.2 ms
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 7 received, 0% packet loss, time 6007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 38.117/38.215/38.482/0.119 ms
[root@localhost network-scripts]# ping 172.16.0.1    
PING 172.16.0.1 (172.16.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.16.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=1.64 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=0.536 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=255 time=0.536 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=255 time=0.554 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=255 time=0.554 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.0.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=255 time=0.552 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.0.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=255 time=0.550 ms
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ping 172.16.0.1
[root@localhost network-scripts]# ping 10.127.111.1
PING 10.127.111.1 (10.127.111.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Please, note that the IP 10.127.111.1 is  related to the leased-line with GW: 172.16.0.1. When i close the second network card (WAN: 10.101.0.10) 10.127.111.1 replays. How can i receive from both cards.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code. Also, please [edit] and explain how you are testing this. What are you trying, what results are you expecting and what results do you actually get?

Comment: @terdon the results i actually get that i can access on card at a time. when closing the first card i can access the second card and vise versa.

Comment: OK, but please [edit] your question and give us the relevant commands (just to check that it isn't something simple like using the wrong command) and their output. Also, thanks for replacing the image with text!

Comment: @terdon does the question now seem realist or not??